# sqoop import from mysql into hbase: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

*my system environment:*

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  (64bit)
Hadoop 2.7.6
HBase 2.0.1
Sqoop 1.4.7
openjdk version 1.8.0_171
```

after starting hadoop services and hbase,
I tried to **import a table from mysql into hbase**:

```
/usr/local/sqoop/bin/sqoop  import 
      --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTDB  
      --table mytable 
      --username <username> 
      --hbase-table hbmytable 
      --column-family  hbmytable_cf 
      --split-by ID 
      --hbase-create-table 
      --password ########
```

however, **import failed** with the following error messages:

```
......
18/08/08 18:41:28 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of mytable
18/08/08 18:41:28 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/08/08 18:41:28 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob.jobSetup(HBaseImportJob.java:163)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:268)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:520)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

---

Is there any work-around ?

Comment: Check that that HBASE_HOME defined in file sqoop-env.sh does exist

Comment: of course this environment variable is set:  `export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase`, and hbase is started successfully before trying to use sqoop.

Comment: I believe that Sqoop 1.4.7 expects HBase 1.2 libraries, not the 2.0 librairies...

Comment: I installed HBase 1.2.5 in order to test this, but with the same sqoop-import statement I now got the error message: (..)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hbase/thirdparty/com/google/protobuf/RpcController
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at (..) org.apache.sqoop.hbase.HBaseUtil.isHBaseJarPresent(HBaseUtil.java:46)
 at (..)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:(..)

Comment: Solving libraries compatibility problems can be very tedious. Why not installing a Hortonworks or Cloudera sandbox?

Comment: You are right: that's a consideration !

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this exception while importing data from MySQL to Hbase.

It seems dependency conflict.

I am using -

```
Hadoop - 3.2.0
Hbase - 2.2.0
Sqoop- 1.4.7
```

I have manually added below mentioned jars in to SQOOP_HOME/lib -

```
1: hbase-client-1.2.0.jar
2: hbase-common-1.2.0.jar
3: hbase-mapreduce-2.2.0.jar
4: hbase-protocol-1.2.0.jar
5: hbase-server-1.2.0.jar
6: hbase-zookeeper-2.2.0.jar
7: protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
```

And Hbase import works fine.

** I am using Hbase 2.2.0 , still I had to use all Hbase-1.2.0 jars.