# When using Sqoop to import data from MySQL into HBase, an error occurred

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I tried to execute the following command

`./bin/sqoop  import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dblab --username root --password 123456 --table user_action --hbase-table user_action --column-family f1 --hbase-row-key id --hbase-create-table -m 1`

But the result was not as expected

Frist
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V`

After that I tried the following example
[sqoop import from mysql into hbase: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755213/sqoop-import-from-mysql-into-hbase-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-hado)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hOMU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5oOY.jpg)

Comment: Your error in the image isn't the one you've provided in the post... You need more jar files